# Change font of default ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to change the font of my ActionBar title. I have found a lot of result ([example1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZ0HKB01aZs), [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607707/how-to-set-a-custom-font-in-the-actionbar-title), [example3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176566/actionbar-title-font-not-changing-in-android), [example4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757373/how-to-change-actionbar-title-font-when-using-appcompat)) about this search but any solves my problem.

I want change the font of default ActionBar which don't have any TextView item that can be called and modify the font. I know I have the posibility to create a custom ActionBar, but I want to try to do this without custom ActionBar.

This is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);
    ...
```

**main1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ActionBar result:**

[image]

What can I do?

Thanks for all.

Comment: If you want to change the Action bar title just give the following 1 line code in the onCreate() of your Activity

`getActionBar().setTitle("Action Bar Title");`

In case you are using support libraries.Use:
`getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Action Bar Title");`

Comment: I don't want change the title but the font of the title

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15181195/5829494 Look at this it might help you. I tried this, it works.Just put the type face in main/assets/fonts

Comment: When I apply this last solution, appear a error _Cannot resolve contructor 'TypefaceSpan(MainActivity, java.lang.string)_ in this part  `s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "Yanone.ttf"), 0, s.length()`. What can I do?

Comment: you have eclosed the `TypefaceSpan` class, right?

Comment: yes! But it still cannot be executed

Comment: can you show me what code you are writing

Comment: Exactly this https://gist.github.com/twaddington/b91341ea5615698b53b8

Comment: I have checked it again its working.Post your `onCreate()` code.

Comment: `SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My Title");
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "Yanone.ttf"), 0, s.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(s);`

Comment: `ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();`

Comment: I have proved it and the problem isn't solved. The problem persist in this part `s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "Yanone.ttf"), 0, s.length()`

Comment: I have just tried it and it is working.I dont know why it is not working.Please provide the activity in which you are using the whole activity with its layout.xml

Answer (score 1):

To change textview's font you can use [Calligraphy library](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

If you want to change ActionBar appearance without custom view you can use styles. For AppTheme you can set custom actionBarStyle.

```
    <style name="MyCustomActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyCustomTextStyleWithFont</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I haven't probe this solution but I have another question: What is better? This solution or create a custom ActionBar?

Comment: With custom view for actionbar you can do whatever you want - add customize layout, add any views and etc. With style you can only change appearance (color, text style, background)

Comment: Ok. Another question: the code You put in your comment is used with Calligraphy Library or without it?

Comment: You can use it without Calligraphy. But you can simply add in future if will needed just add fontPath in MyCustomTextStyleWithFont.

Comment: Have you checked Calligraphy Library? When I try to add the dependenci and I sync the Gradle File appear this error: _Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'._

Comment: Your error don't apply to  Calligraphy. I use Calligraphy  and it works fine.